# 常にUISearchbarを表示

Tags: ios

iOSのGoogleMapアプリのようにメニューのViewが開いてもそのViewController内で、常に最前面にUISearchbarを表示するにはどうすればよいですか？

以下がイメージです。
[image: メニューを開く前]     [image: メニューを開いた後]

Comment: 画面キャプチャなどを添付するとイメージが伝わりやすくなると思います。Viewの階層構造の関係でWindow上にViewをaddSubviewすると、大抵最前面になります。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。イメージを追加しました。
AppDelegateのwindowに追加するのでしょうか。そうしましたら他のViewに遷移しても残ってしまいました。

Comment: 「常に最前面」との事でしたらWindowでも良いと思いましたが、「ViewController内で」などの条件があれば質問に追記すると、さらに良くなると思います。

Answer (score 1):

## はじめに

`UIViewController`内で通常、ベースとなるViewはプロパティの`view`になります。
この`view`に何かのViewを`addSubview:`すると、そのViewが最前面になります。

つまり、一番最後に`addSubview:`したViewが最前面になる訳ですが、普通は画面の初期表示の後にもユーザーイベント等をトリガーとして`addSubview:`する事があります。

ここで、Viewを最前面にするメソッドとして、`bringSubviewToFront:`があります。
このメソッドを使うとそのViewに貼られているSubViewを最前面にする事ができます。

## 回答

質問のひとつの解決手段として、**viewプロパティにaddSubview:されるタイミングでbringSubviewToFront:を呼ぶ** を提案します。

まず、対象の`UIViewController`のサブクラスのプロパティ`view`を下記のようなUIViewサブクラスで置き換えます。(xibやstoryboard上又はloadView等で)

```
@interface MyView : UIView
// 最前面に置きたいView
@property(nonatomic,weak)UIView* frontView;
@end

@implementation MyView
// addSubview:される時に呼ばれる
- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview
{
    // 最前面にする
    if (self.frontView) {
        [self bringSubviewToFront:self.frontView];
    }
}

@end
```

次に、最前面に置きたいView(ここではUISearchbar)を生成時に、上記クラスのプロパティ`frontView`にセットしておく。(下記参照)

```
[(MyView*)self.view setFrontView:searchbar];
```

そうすると、設定したViewControllerの`view`に`addSubview:`される度に`didAddSubview:`が呼ばれ、`frontView`にセットしたViewが最前面になる処理が呼ばれます。